# Drupal: MQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 INSERT command denied to user when accessing any page with a form

Tags: drupal, ovh

My Drupal website hosted on OVH was functioning normally and everything was working fine.
Now when I try to access any page containing a form, it displays this error, even though I haven't made any changes or modifications:

*The website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later. Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 INSERT command denied to user 'xxxxxxx'@'xx.xx.xx.xx' for table 'watchdog': INSERT INTO "watchdog" ...

....

ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED.

Comment: Disable the Database Logging module (drush pmu dblog -y) and see whether the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed!

1. After checking OVH, I discovered that the database was full and had become **Read Only**, preventing access to pages that require data insertion.
2. Identified the table with the maximum size; in my case, I found that the cache table had the largest size. Cleared the cache table to free up space.
3. Restarted the quota on OVH, and verified the database size.
4. Now it's green, with more space, and the pages work fine.
5. Configured cache performance in Drupal and activated cache clearing.